# Wxpython dynamic programming

Tags: wxpython

Im a newbie to Wxpython programming and I have a general on how to make my application more program.

Assume, I have a tree with the list of employees being listed in the tree.  When I click a employee the information is retrieved in the db and the information is diplayed on the right side of the panel.

Now, when I edit information of one of the employee and save it again the data the current row in the table needs to be end dated and the new row will be created in the db and also refreshing the tree.

So, Basically if something is saved the tree should be refreshed automatically.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the default TreeCtrl has database interaction builtin. You would have to add that. If you want it to check for updates periodically, you could use a wx.Timer. If you'll be updating the database with your wxPython GUI, then there shouldn't be a problem as you'll have to update the display anyway.

You might also want to look at the DVC_DataViewModel in the wxPython demo. I think it may make this sort of thing easier as it has the concept of data objects, which I think implies that you could create a database object to feed your GUI.